# How to connect to dataverse rest api from sharepoint online webpart

Tags: spfx, dataverse

It seems to be hard finding a good sample or article on this and i was hoping to get some links to samples or articles with regards to configuring this. Or if someone has some experience connecting to dataverse from spfx webparts? caveats and something?

Comment: Bit old, but I'd love to know if there are any tutorials for this.